# How to derive the backward Fokker-Planck equation from a forward Fokker-Planck equation (with state-dependent diffusion coefficient)?

Tags: diffusion, stochastic-processes

I am interested in a system with state-dependent diffusion coefficients. This [paper by Lau and Lubensky](http://www.lpsm.paris/pageperso/lecomte/references2014/lau-lubensky_2007.pdf) derives the correct Forward FPE in this case:

$$\partial_tP(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} D(x) \Bigg(\beta \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Bigg) P(x,t)$$

I want to find the corresponding backwards FPE, however since this is not the standard form, I have not been able to find a derivation which applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the inner product $\langle f, g\rangle = \int fg \,\mathrm{d}x$. Define also the adjoint $\mathcal{A}^\dagger$ of $\mathcal{A}$ as one satisfying $\langle \mathcal{A}f,g\rangle = \langle f, \mathcal{A}^\dagger g\rangle$ for all $f, g$. Obviously $(\mathcal{A}^\dagger)^\dagger = \mathcal{A}$.

Given the forward FPE:
$$\partial_t p = \mathcal{L}_t p, \quad \text{with} \quad p(x, 0) = \delta(x - x_0)$$
And the backward FPE:
$$\partial_t u = \mathcal{B}_t u, \quad \text{with} \quad u(x, T) = f(x)$$

Now for these to be the forward and the backward PDE, they have to be connected.

Now clearly $\mathbb{E}(f(X_T) | X_0 = x_0) = \int p(x, T)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \langle p(\bullet, T), f\rangle$ where $p$ is a solution to the forward FPE starting from $x_0$. This has to equal the backward solution $u(x_0, 0)$, as it is just diffusing $f$ from $T$ to the starting point.

We thus have $\langle p(\bullet, T), u(\bullet, T) \rangle = \langle p(\bullet, T), f\rangle = u(x_0, 0) = \langle u(\bullet, 0), p(\bullet, 0) \rangle$, and so:
\begin{align}
0 &= \langle p(\bullet, T), u(\bullet, T) \rangle - \langle u(\bullet, 0), p(\bullet, 0) \rangle \\
&= \int_0^T \left(\langle \partial_t p, u \rangle + \langle p, \partial_t u\rangle\right)\,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_0^T \left(\langle \mathcal{L}_t p, u \rangle + \langle p, \mathcal{B}_t u \rangle\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}

This is always true if we define, as one does, the backwards operator as $\mathcal{B}_t = -\mathcal{L}_t^\dagger$.

Ok, so that was a long reminder (+ some intuition) of the definition of the backwards operator as the (minus) adjoint of the forward. So taking the adjoint of the forward operator we're done:

Given arbitrary $f, g$ and defining $\mathcal{L} = \partial_x D (\beta \mathcal{H}' + \partial_x)$:
\begin{align}
\langle \mathcal{L} f, g\rangle &= \int \left(\partial_x D (\beta \mathcal{H}' + \partial_x) f\right) g\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\int \left(D (\beta \mathcal{H}' + \partial_x) f\right) \partial_x g\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\int f D \beta \mathcal{H}'\partial_x g + (\partial_x f) D \partial_x g\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\int f D \beta \mathcal{H}'\partial_x g - f \partial_x D \partial_x g\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \langle f, \mathcal{L}^\dagger g\rangle
\end{align}
where we have defined $\mathcal{L}^\dagger = -(D \beta \mathcal{H}' - \partial_x D )\partial_x$, which is to say that the backwards FPE comes out as:
$$\frac{\partial u(x, t)}{\partial t} = \left(D(x) \beta \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} D(x) \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x, t)$$

In closing, let's do a simple and crude numerical experiment of the example B in the paper, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x} = 0$, $D(x) = 1 - x^2$ (for $L=1$). We compute the PDF at time 0.1 using the forward equation given the the initial condition $x_0 = 0$, and then we solve the backwards equation $f(x) = \max(x, 0)$ and confirm that the expectations match:

```
import numpy as np
TT = np.linspace(0, .1, 8192)
XX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 51)
dt = np.diff(TT)[0]
dx = np.diff(XX)[0]
D = 1 - XX**2

p  = np.zeros(len(XX))
p[(len(XX)-1)//2] = 1./dx
u  = np.array([max(x, 0) for x in XX])

for t in TT:
    p[1:-1] += dt * (np.diff(D[1:] * np.diff(p)/dx)/dx)
    u[1:-1] += -dt * (-np.diff(D[1:] * np.diff(u)/dx)/dx)

print(u[(len(XX)-1)//2], np.sum(np.array([max(x, 0) for x in XX]) * p * dx))
```

Prints

```
0.15722869700957792 0.15722869700957764
```

Comment: Hello @alarge, thanks for a detailed answer. Could you point to literature, where the backward equation is defined as a minus self-adjoint of a forward version?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_backward_equations_(diffusion), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itô_diffusion. In the physics books that I have at hand, the relation is usually stated as fact, and I don't really have any good sources of formal mathematics where equivalences between different definitions are proven. That said, Oksendal has an exercise to prove that the adjoint of the generator of Ito diffusion satisfies the forward equation (note though that mathematicians often start from t=0 and go forwards rather than t=T and go backwards, and so differ by a minus sign)

Comment: thanks. I did not read Oksendal, but I am familiar with Gardiner's and Risken's books on stochastic processes. In these books, both of the backward and forward KE are derived from the Chapman-Kolgorov formula, and then it is stated that the reader can verify that the results are adjoints of each other.

Comment: @alarge I cannot see why $\langle p(\bullet, T), f\rangle = u(x_0, 0)$, could you give some insight?

Comment: @Javi Think of the forward FPE as diffusing a particle given its initial position, and the expectation as us wanting to compute some function $f$ of its position at T. The backward FPE in contrast, is to ask that given we know $f$ at T, what value of $f$ would you expect to land on if we were to go backwards in time? If we go all the way to the beginning, we'll have the expected value for all initial positions, and in particular when the initial position coincidences with the one used in the forward FPE, so the solutions too must be the same.